# How to resolve Dplyr Install Error in R Studio?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to install the dplyr package (install.packages("dplyr")), but am receiving the following error:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/vctrs_0.6.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 967338 bytes (944 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 944 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dplyr_1.1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1083635 bytes (1.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.0 MB

* installing *source* package ‘vctrs’ ...
** package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘vctrs’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/vctrs’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/dplyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/8g/ktjdvdpn2j35mbml3rw72s7r0000gn/T/RtmpXpeqcD/downloaded_packages’
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

I am using the most current version of R studio and I have tried installing "lifecycles" before but this did not help.

Comment: Hi Walter! Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems like there is a problem with your CommandLineTools install. I would suggest reinstalling it as a first step- more info here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93573/how-to-reinstall-xcode-command-line-tools